# How do I remove text from my lock screen on my nextbook?

Tags: lock-screens, lookout

I downloaded the Lookout security app. The first time I installed it it asked for something to write when I report my device was stolen. After deleting the app numerous times it still will not remove the text. How do I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Lookout just used the standard "owner info" and your device uses the same...

```
Settings > Security > Owner info
```

Then uncheck "Show owner info on lock screen" or edit the text to be what you want.